# IndexError: list index out of range. (trying to find and substitute elements of one txt file with another txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

beginning python programmer here. I am currently stuck with writing a small python script that would open a txt source file, find a specific number in that source file with a regular expression (107.5 in this case) and ultimately replace that 107.5 with a new number. the new number comes from a second txt file which contains 30 numbers. Each time a number has been replaced, the script uses the next number for its replacement. Although the command prompt does seem to print a successfull find and replace, "an IndexError: list index out of range" occurs after the 30th loop...

My hunge is that I somehow have to limit my loop with something like "for i in range x". However I am not sure which list this should be and how I can incorporate that loop limitation in my current code. Any help is much appreciated!

```
nTemplate = [" "]

output = open(r'C:\Users\Sammy\Downloads\output.txt','rw+')

count = 0

for line in templateImport:
   priceValue = re.compile(r'107.5')

   if priceValue.sub(pllines[count], line) != None:
      priceValue.sub(pllines[count], line)
      nTemplate.append(line)
      count = count + 1
      print('found a match. replaced ' + '107.5 ' + 'with ' + pllines[count] )
      print(nTemplate)

   else:
      nTemplate.append(line)
```

Comment: Can you give us the first and second txt? Or at least what it looks like?

Comment: The first file is orginally a large .XML file. this is the file that needs to be amended. The second file is a small (30 lines) .txt file with just the raw values that I want to amend the XML file with. The answer of TheGamer007 helped me out already but any extra comments are welcome ofcourse!

Answer (score 0):

The `IndexError` is raised because you are incrementing `count` in each iteration of the loop, but haven't added an upper limit based on how many values the `pllines` list actually contains. You should break out of the loop when it reaches `len(pllines)` in order to avoid the error.

Another issue which you may not have noticed is with your usage of the `re.sub()` method. It returns a new string with the appropriate replacements, and does not modify the original.

If the pattern doesn't exist in the string, it'll return the original itself. So your `nTemplate` list probably never had any of the replaced strings appended to it. Unless you need to do some other actions if the pattern was found in the line, you can do away with the `if` condition (as I have in the example below).

Since the `priceValue` object is the same for all lines, it can be moved outside the loop.

The following code should work:

```
nTemplate = [" "]
output = open(r'C:\Users\Sammy\Downloads\output.txt','rw+')

count = 0
priceValue = re.compile(r'107.5')

for line in templateImport:
    if count == len(pllines):
        break
    nTemplate.append(priceValue.sub(pllines[count], line))
    count = count + 1
    print(nTemplate)
```

Comment: My gratitude is great TheGamer007. I was not aware of the fact that re.sub also returned original lines without the substitution. Again thanks alot, it works!

Comment: Happy to help. Please mark the answer as 'Accepted' if it worked for you.